# How do I request for expert review of my answer?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I am a newbie and I wrote and answer that works. It teaches you how to install ruby gems in eclipse without all the commandline stuff. But, I am not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem. Maybe the expert or professional developers will see some shortcomings or improvements in my answer. So, how do I request experts for reviews ? I want to make a good answer and possibly convert it into a wiki for the benefit of everyone. Please advise !

My post - [Can a ruby gem/module be added just like a java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288995/can-a-ruby-gem-module-be-added-just-like-a-java-jar-file)

Comment: [SE Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be an appropriate site.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Its not really code, but just how to setup a ruby project. So, I am not sure if code review would be the best option. Thanks.

Comment: You might pop into an appropriate room on [chat] and ask for someone to look over it.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but do note that punctuation, like the question mark and exclamation point, should not have a space before them. See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4645.

Answer (score 8):

Your answer gets an expert review at the moment it is posted. Most seasoned users have a browser tab open on active posts. Once the post pops up they will see it and either vote, edit, or comment.

If your answer consist of working code and you rather have a code review done you can ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as suggested by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96) but make sure to read their [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) help topic.

If you want an extra pair of eyes to proof-read before posting, you can always try the advice offered by [icktoofay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/200291/icktoofay) and head to one of the many [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Most language stacks have their own room. Make sure to check if the room has particular rules before rushing in.

If none of those options work you might want to check if a colleague, classmate, or friend is willing to act as a rubber duck.